# Catch error in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, transactions

I want to implement a batch MySQL script to do something in a database. The thing is that, for each master id that I have I want to insert 4 tuples. But this tuples should be added in a transaction which means if one of these 4 tuples is failed the transaction should be rollback. Then I need to have some catching mechanism to capture that the query is failed. I CAN ONLY USE PURE MYSQL neither PHP, nor PERL etc. Even I cannot create any store procedure to do that. In Microsoft SQL Server there is @@error variable that solved my problem but in MYSQL we do not have any system variables showing the error code.
how can I do that?

Cheers,

Comment: I want to catch it to rollback the transaction

Comment: Why can't you wrap the 'batch MYSQL' script in a PHP wrapper? Then you can use try/catch with rollback/commit.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly workaround, but it worked for me when I was trying to import a batch of SQL queries and wrap the entire thing within a transaction, so that I could roll back if any of the SQL queries errored.

Since the size of the batch was massive, a SQL procedure with condition handler was not an option either.

You have to do this **manually**, so it really isn't a solution unless you are batching:

First, make sure your entire batch is stored in an SQL file. The SQL file should only contain the batch queries, and no transaction control queries.

Then start up a MySQL command line client and type in transaction commands manually:

```
mysql> SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
mysql> START TRANSACTION;
```

Then tell the command line client to run the batch file:

```
mysql> SOURCE path/to/file.sql
```

After that you can simply manually `COMMIT;` or `ROLLBACK;` depending on how happy you are with the result of your queries.

This is such a kludge, though. Anyone have a better approach?